# Adams P5EC5E method

Tags: matlab

I am looking for such a data set but for the P5EC5E Adams method.
It is to obtain the best step value (`h`) for this method.
I got these values for the P3EC3E but I don't know how to obtain `y1` and `y2` set.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
t=[ 0 0.333333 0.666667 1 1.33333 1.66667 2 2.33333 2.66667 3 3.33333 3.66667 4 4.33333 4.66667 5 5.33333 5.66667 6 6.33333 6.66667 7 7.33333 7.66667 8 8.33333 8.66667 9 9.33333 9.66667 10 10.3333 10.6667 11 11.3333 11.6667 12 12.3333 12.6667 13 13.3333 13.6667 14 14.3333 14.6667 15 15.3333 15.6667 16 16.3333 16.6667 17 17.3333 17.6667 18 18.3333 18.6667 19 19.3333 19.6667 20 20.3333 20.6667 21 21.3333 21.6667 22 22.3333 22.6667 23 23.3333 23.6667 24 24.3333 24.6667 25 25.3333 25.6667 26 26.3333 26.6667 27 27.3333 27.6667 28 28.3333 28.6667 29 29.3333 29.6667 30 30.3333 30.6667 31 31.3333 31.6667 32 32.3333 32.6667 33 33.3333 33.6667 34 34.3333 34.6667 35 35.3333 35.6667 36 36.3333 36.6667 37 37.3333 37.6667 38 38.3333 38.6667 39 39.3333 39.6667 40 ];

y1=[ 0.95 0.971051 0.887193 0.724159 0.529811 0.36102 0.24217 0.158434 0.102306 0.0672892 0.0440178 0.0297163 0.0200929 0.0139717 0.00970338 0.00686779 0.00483484 0.00344521 0.00243814 0.00174013 0.00123376 0.000880468 0.000624738 0.000445634 0.000316342 0.000225546 0.000160164 0.000114149 8.10824e-05 5.77693e-05 4.10448e-05 2.92359e-05 2.07763e-05 1.47957e-05 1.05164e-05 7.48787e-06 5.32297e-06 3.78951e-06 2.69423e-06 1.91784e-06 1.36367e-06 9.70611e-07 6.90209e-07 4.91226e-07 3.4934e-07 2.4861e-07 1.76813e-07 1.25823e-07 8.94907e-08 6.36797e-08 4.52939e-08 3.22288e-08 2.29245e-08 1.63113e-08 1.16027e-08 8.2553e-09 5.87247e-09 4.17808e-09 2.97222e-09 2.11456e-09 1.50433e-09 1.07019e-09 7.61388e-10 5.4163e-10 3.85365e-10 2.74118e-10 1.95049e-10 1.38729e-10 9.87238e-11 7.02085e-11 4.99701e-11 3.55303e-11 2.52938e-11 1.798e-11 1.28038e-11 9.09815e-12 6.48182e-12 4.6034e-12 3.28171e-12 2.3289e-12 1.66176e-12 1.17799e-12 8.41653e-13 5.95687e-13 4.26416e-13 3.01113e-13 2.16137e-13 1.52125e-13 1.09624e-13 7.67942e-14 5.56529e-14 3.87218e-14 2.82909e-14 1.94921e-14 1.44088e-14 9.78823e-15 7.35836e-15 4.89784e-15 3.77214e-15 2.43796e-15 1.94409e-15 1.20407e-15 1.0094e-15 5.87671e-16 5.29427e-16 2.81594e-16 2.81472e-16 1.30979e-16 1.5231e-16 5.78804e-17 8.42666e-17 2.31655e-17 4.78808e-17 7.25828e-18 2.80459e-17 4.18903e-19 1.69729e-17 -2.15973e-18 1.0615e-17 -2.82143e-18 6.84784e-18 ];

y2=[ -0.25 0.0887269 0.359344 0.524747 0.569731 0.514569 0.418495 0.320075 0.228782 0.157155 0.103759 0.0665426 0.0416129 0.0254965 0.0153813 0.00914669 0.00539722 0.00314755 0.00183588 0.0010554 0.000614267 0.000347627 0.000204522 0.000112486 6.86959e-05 3.52857e-05 2.38512e-05 1.02158e-05 8.97938e-06 2.2182e-06 3.95131e-06 -2.26605e-07 2.16284e-06 -8.83955e-07 1.45231e-06 -9.79326e-07 1.11156e-06 -9.09115e-07 9.07186e-07 -7.99846e-07 7.60861e-07 -6.90523e-07 6.45103e-07 -5.91981e-07 5.49261e-07 -5.06164e-07 4.68413e-07 -4.32354e-07 3.99711e-07 -3.69167e-07 3.41166e-07 -3.15169e-07 2.91221e-07 -2.69055e-07 2.48597e-07 -2.29683e-07 2.12214e-07 -1.96071e-07 1.81157e-07 -1.67377e-07 1.54645e-07 -1.42882e-07 1.32014e-07 -1.21972e-07 1.12694e-07 -1.04122e-07 9.62017e-08 -8.8884e-08 8.2123e-08 -7.58762e-08 7.01046e-08 -6.47721e-08 5.98451e-08 -5.5293e-08 5.10871e-08 -4.72011e-08 4.36107e-08 -4.02934e-08 3.72285e-08 -3.43967e-08 3.17802e-08 -2.93629e-08 2.71293e-08 -2.50657e-08 2.31591e-08 -2.13975e-08 1.97699e-08 -1.8266e-08 1.68766e-08 -1.55929e-08 1.44068e-08 -1.33109e-08 1.22984e-08 -1.13629e-08 1.04986e-08 -9.70003e-09 8.96219e-09 -8.28047e-09 7.65061e-09 -7.06866e-09 6.53098e-09 -6.03419e-09 5.5752e-09 -5.15112e-09 4.75929e-09 -4.39727e-09 4.06279e-09 -3.75375e-09 3.46822e-09 -3.20441e-09 2.96066e-09 -2.73546e-09 2.52738e-09 -2.33513e-09 2.15751e-09 -1.9934e-09 1.84177e-09 -1.70167e-09 1.57223e-09 -1.45264e-09 1.34214e-09 ];

plot(t,y1,t,y2,'r-');
grid on;
```

Comment: Adams' method is a numerical method for solving linear first-order ODEs but on the other hand it seems you are uncertain about best step interval. These are 2 different questions. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the best step interval

Answer (score -1):

If you have your data set, the best step interval is `h=X(i+1)-X(i)` where `i` is from `1` to `n-1` and you will calculate your problems by multiple steps. In your example, `h` is constant and equal to `1/3`.

If it is a function instead of data set, as you are the one who determines the step size, the answers will be more accurate as long as you decrease step interval and there is no unique `h`.

Please clarify your problem if this is not what you are looking for or you are not getting replies to this problem.